# why does SELECT statement doesn't get executed by EVENT scheduler in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i am learning to create **event** in mysql, i tried sucessfully insert, update and delete commands.
but with SELECT statement, it doesn't show the output.

```
mysql> CREATE EVENT e_totals ON SCHEDULE AT '2013-06-04 23:59:00' DO INSERT INTO test.totals VALUES (NOW());
```

the above event works fine.
but the event below isn't not working...

```
mysql> CREATE EVENT e_totals ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 seconds DO SELECT * FROM test.totals;
```

i've set all the global parameters and also enabled the event.
what i am doing wrong????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Answer:

> Statements such as SELECT or SHOW that merely return a result set have no effect when used in an event; the output from these is not sent to the MySQL Monitor, nor is it stored anywhere. However, you can use statements such as SELECT ... INTO and INSERT INTO ... SELECT that store a result. (See the next example in this section for an instance of the latter.)